# What does "nothing could be further from correct" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *nothing could be further from correct* mean?

For example,

> It is not OK to stop paying rents. This approach seems to be popular
>   with tenants, and **nothing could be further from correct**. You have the choices of waiting for him to repair the leaking roof, or of moving out when your tenancy agreement expires.

Comment: One clarification: What exactly is the popular approach with tenants? Have they stopped paying rents or do they think it is not ok to stop paying rents?

Comment: @Irene: I added more detail.

Comment: Ok, that helped. In this context, Jasper Loy's answer is the one you are looking for.

Comment: The more usual expression is "nothing could be further from the truth".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means in this case that to stop paying rents is definitely not correct. It is so wrong that nothing could be more wrong.